# A WPF app builds on my machine, but does not in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild

We're working on a WPF app using .NET Framework 4.7.2. We utilize a NuGet package called Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, version 12.0.5000. It wasn't building in Azure DevOps (it has never built there), but we need Microsoft.SqlServer.Types for reports. I cloned it to a new machine, in an effort to try to figure out what was wrong. I got errors with Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, in particular with it claiming it could not find SqlServerSpatial120.dll and msvcr100.dll in the project, but both are there. So, I removed the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package, then put it back in again. It now builds fine on my machine. So, I committed that change, then pushed to Azure DevOps, where I ran the build pipeline, but it failed again, with the following errors:

> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7366010Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): Error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x64\SqlServerSpatial120.dll'.
> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7374263Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x64\SqlServerSpatial120.dll'. [D:\a\1\s\ACDC\ACDC.csproj]
> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7378901Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): Error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x64\msvcr100.dll'.
> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7381193Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x64\msvcr100.dll'. [D:\a\1\s\ACDC\ACDC.csproj]
> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7388245Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): Error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial120.dll'.
> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7451411Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial120.dll'. [D:\a\1\s\ACDC\ACDC.csproj]
> 2021-07-21T20:24:48.7456054Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): Error MSB3113: Could not find file 'SqlServerTypes\x86\msvcr100.dll'.

The portion of the YAML build file doesn't have much, here it is:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- name: solution
  value: '**/*.sln'
- name: buildPlatform
  value: 'Any CPU'
- name:  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE
  value: true
- name:  buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name:  Binaries
  value: test
- group: 'acdc-pipeline-group'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/target:publish
                  /p:ApplicationRevision=$(Build.BuildId)'
```

It fails in the VSBuild@1 step. Why is it I can build this app on my development box, but cannot build it using an Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Comment: Are you using one of Microsoft's build servers or your own or your own organization's that someone configured manually? It almost looks like the VS installation on the build box doesn't have a prerequisite you need.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's build servers. I agree that it appears like the Microsoft build servers don't appear to have the prerequisites needed to perform the build. That's what puzzles me. I would have thought that the NuGetToolInstaller@1 task would make those prerequisites available.

Comment: Yeah agreed. Sorry I don't have any other ideas. FWIW after similar issues I just sucked it up and built my own build server with a relatively cheap Azure VM and VS Community. Then I was able to remote in, make sure VS and everything else I needed was installed exactly to my requirements, and build it manually while remoting in to troubleshoot until I got it working. I get the sense that the MS build servers are good for cookie cutter stuff but not much else.

Comment: You point, Peter. I'm trying to do a build of a ClickOnce app. ClickOnce is popular, but not hugely popular.